# Office COMAddin and VBA

Tags: vba

I installed the third party COM Addin in my Office 2010 on Win7 - it's a dll which converts Office document to a DjVu document. When I access it interactively from Office program I can produce the document I want and everything is working just great.

What I need is to automate the process of converting hundreds of office documents. I came to an idea of creating the macro, saving it in normal.dot and executing it when the document is opened.

I created the VBA piece of code (below) that allows me to create the DjVu document - but that is not working as I expected. The result is so different I decided to ask for your help.

**When I execute below Macro I get the following:**

1. file named as expected and located where expected
2. content of the file is not DjVu but PDF

But when I execute the Add-in interactively in the Office App I get the DjVu content instead of PDF.

What am I missing?
It's probably a simple mistake (like making sure the Addin is actually being called/referred to but I failed finding the way to do that)...

Any help with examples would be appreciated

```
Sub Export2DjVu()
'
' Export2DjVu Macro
'
'
Dim FileName As String
Dim NewFileName As String
Dim DjVuTargetFolder As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim myAddIn As addin


    DjVuTargetFolder = Environ("Cyfrad_Office_Djvu")
    FileName = ActiveDocument.Name
    i = Len(FileName)
    While (Mid(FileName, i, 1) <> ".") And (i <> 0)
      i = i - 1
    Wend
    If i = 0 Then NewFileName = FileName
    If i <> 0 Then NewFileName = Left(FileName, i - 1)
    NewFileName = DjVuTargetFolder & "\" & NewFileName & ".djvu"

    ActiveDocument.ExportAsFixedFormat OutputFileName:= _
        NewFileName, ExportFormat:= _
        wdExportFormatPDF, OpenAfterExport:=False, OptimizeFor:= _
        wdExportOptimizeForPrint, Range:=wdExportAllDocument, From:=1, To:=1, _
        Item:=wdExportDocumentContent, IncludeDocProps:=True, KeepIRM:=False, _
        CreateBookmarks:=wdExportCreateWordBookmarks, DocStructureTags:=True, _
        BitmapMissingFonts:=True, UseISO19005_1:=False
    ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub
```

Comment: Is there an API for the add-in? You seem to be using pure VBA to export the file as PDF and I do not see you using the add-in classes to export the file. How does the add-in work? I mean, do you just click a button on ribbon or something like that to export a document as `DjVu`? You need to know which procedure to call from the add-in and then probably create an object of the add-in class in VBA and then call the appropriate method for exporting possibly passing the filename or the document itself as a parameter

Comment: The only file I've got are two DLLs and that's it.
In interactive way I need to click on a ribbon and the window pops up to tell the Addin where to put the output file...
This is all I have / know...

Comment: Well, once you add references to the *.tlb (rather than .dll even thought that works with automation add-ins I remember correctly) open VBE and hit F2 to see Object Browser. Then where it says `<all libraries>` expand it and see if you can find your library there. Can you see the library you've references? We need more details to be able to help you. Is that library for converting free? Can we download it?

Comment: I can see the list of object but that is meaningless to me :(

The library is free and you can download it from here:
http://www.djvu.pl/download/Office2DjVuSetup.msi

You could aslodownload from the same site the DjVu viewer to be able to check if the file created is really a DjVu one and not the PDF as in my case (the size would be different anyway despite the extension so you should notice without actually installing the viewer)
DjVu is much smaller size than PDF

Comment: Well, say you work with MS Word. Open the document, then depending on the version of the Office look for the option you can use this add-in (in 2010 I use it's at the bottom of the File menu under the button Add-ins). Chiise 'Save As' option and then DjVu Format. You'll see the window to specify the name and location of the output file. Click save and the conversion process starts. Now all I want is to automate that somehow.. I thought of a batch file as this is something I am familiar with :) Hope thius helps

Comment: yea [I see that](http://djvu.pl/news-Office2DjvuSetup.php). Now even if I reference the `Office2DjVu.dll` as a COM library via TOOLs -> REFERENCES it does not expose a method for initializing the procedure. All I can see are 2 classes `CallbackInterface` and `Connect` and only the first one exposes 3 functions `ConvButtonClicked`, `OnLoad` and `GetImage`. I can't find any documentation on those 3 but I wouldn't hope they would allow you to instantiate the object needed to save the file as `djvu`. Based on that I would rather assume that it's possible to automate this library.

Comment: Therefore the only way is to probably use WinAPI.. risky but there probably isn't any other way. You may send the developer of the library an email and ask but I can't help any further here, maybe someone else more experienced than me can...

Comment: [**This**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373080/call-com-add-in-via-vba-in-excel) is somehow familiar but not exactly as you do not know how to trigger the add-in initialization.